# Condenser microphone + LM386 + Arduino

Tags: arduino, lm386, electret, condenser-microphone

I found this simple circuit and I set it up with BCM-9767P, LM386N and tried to write out the values I get. The problem is that the values seem to be constant and don't change with the environment sound level. I think I followed everything on the circuit, even changed the microphone resistor according to its database.

How can I make it work?

[image: wiring diagram]

[image: photo of breadboard circuit]

Comment: Are you aware that when it does work that you are going to feed alternating signals (alternating positive and negative) into the ADC of the microcontroller which can only accept positive values? This may destroy the chip's ADC (if it hasn't already). Test the ADC with a pot or a pair of equal value resistors as a potential divider and see if you get a reading around 500 out of the ADC.

Comment: You have *some* ground connections to the top blue common, and *some* ground connections to the bottom blue common.....these two blue commons must be jumped together. Your photo shows no connection.

Comment: There also seems to be no resistor that matches a 1k resistor going from mic to 5V. Some weird resistor going to ground is there. But it is not easy to track what goes where from the photo. I also noticed there is no ground connection between upper and lower ground buses.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I made more photos of the circiut.
https://imgur.com/a/r7slgH0
The two ground and vc is connected on the other side

Comment: LM386 is a (small) audio output amplifier, making it an odd choice for a mic amp. You'd be better using a suitable opamp, and may need to set it for something like 60dB gain.

Comment: as others pointed out, you are using an audio POWER amp (which is intended for driving a speaker from a more or less line level source) when you actually want a mic PREAMP (which converts a low level mic signal to line level). Search on "electret preamp" and you will find multiple ideas to do this. (The type of mic you are using is an electret, and yes, this matters.)

Comment: In addition to what @danmcb said, note that the datasheet for your microphone element calls for a load resistance (the 100Ω/1kΩ in your circuit) of 2.2kΩ when used with a 5V supply.  (This is related to the characteristics of a field effect transistor that is part of the microphone element.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few comments to your original post that I'll reiterate here, along with my own thoughts.

Transistor said that your ADC is being exposed to negative voltages, which could damage it. He's right, and the culprit is C3. That output from the LM386 (in this application) should be a voltage between 0V and +5V, which as it happens is quite compatible with the ADC, and should not break it. C3, however removes any average DC from the signal and causes the signal to vary between +2.5V and -2.5V, which would definitely harm the ADC. To fix this, remove C3, and replace it with a direct connection. Better still, replace it with a 1k resistor, which will limit current into the ADC in case of excursions outside the 0-5V range, while not messing with the signal to any great degree.

The second point is that the LM386 is a power amplifier, designed to deliver large currents to a heavy load, like a speaker. This was pointed out by user_1818839 and danmcb. The role of the 10Ω resistor R2 is to simulate the presence of that speaker, which *may* be necessary for the LM386 to function properly. It is however wasteful, and R2 is eating up power unnecessarily, and getting warm. If you use a battery to power this thing, R2 will be the biggest consumer of energy here. Later I'll draw a circuit which will not suffer from this problem.

There was a hint in your question that you are trying to measure sound *level*, which is not the same as measuring the instantaneous value of the waveform. The latter (which amounts to digitising the waveform itself) doesn't require anything special (except a guarantee that the signal doesn't ever fall outside the 0-5V range that the ADC expects), you just connect the signal directly to the ADC input. To derive a signal corresponding to the sound *level*, however, requires something that detects *peaks* in the waveform, not the waveform itself. I'll show you a solution for that also later.

Various users have commented that the breadboard layout you have implemented does not seem to be complete. From the picture it seems that the lower two bus lines (the long red and blue horizontal strips) are not connected to any power rails. It looks like you only use the lower (blue) bus, so at the least you'll have to explicitly connect that to 0V, with a wire. Ironically, this may have saved your ADC, because without a 0V connection to the LM386's power pin, its output can't swing up and down between 0V and 5V, and the right side of C3 therefore can't become negative.

A better amplifier, which doesn't chew up power like R2 does here, uses a regular op-amp. Your best choice of opamp is one with a rail-to-rail output, such as the [TLC2272/TLC2274](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc2272a.pdf). The cheap and ubiquitous [LM358/LM324](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf) will work too, but with a 5V supply, its output will be constrained to within 0V and about +4V.

My first suggestion would be this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fom2I4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This has a gain of about 180, just like your LM386, and will amplify signals from about 50Hz to 2kHz (I estimate) by that amount. You can connect OUT directly to your ADC without fear of damaging it, since the output never wanders outside the 0V to 5V range. The output is centered at about 2V, so that will be the "quiet" level your ADC can expect.

I haven't included the microphone here, since we don't know whether it's an electret or moving coil device. Either way, you should be able to take an audio signal of a few millivolts from any source, and get a volt or so excursion at the output.

To make a peak detector (if that's what you intended), you could use an extra diode, capacitor and resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Dk6D.png)</sup>

It's crude, but it works. When the opamp output rises, diode D1 becomes forward biased, conducting well to charge the capacitor. When the opamp output falls again, below the voltage on C3, D1 becomes reverse biased, effectively disconnecting the opamp from C3. C3 is then able to hold on to its charge, maintaining the peak voltage it was initially charged with. R6 allows C3 to discharge slowly, eventually allowing it to return to its no-signal level, after a couple of seconds.

The diode causes the quiescent output level to drop by half a volt or so, so you can expect the output to be about 1.5V when there's no input signal, rising to a maximum of about 3.5V when things get loud.

Also, in both circuits the opamp is quite noisy, so expect your ADC to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that your microphone only has one connection, and that's to ground.

Solderless breadboards only have connections between pins in certain directions.  As far as I can tell, you are expecting the breadboard to "know" which direction you intend the connections to go.

The strips along the outside are connected together the long way down the breadboard.

The fields inside the breadboard are connected the short way across the board - but they do not cross the groove that runs the length of the board down the center.

Look at your breadboard.  It has numbered rows, and columns with letters.  In each row, columns a, b, c, d, and e are connected together.  Also, columns f, g, h, i, and j are connected together.

The numbered rows are not connected to each other at all.

Check your circuit as built against the schematic diagram, and keep in mind which way the breadboard connections run.

I'm pretty sure you'll find more wrong than just the microphone.

Comment: The microphone is connected to two different "short way" line. I take out the microphone to see. https://i.imgur.com/lAFnnYt.jpg